# Adobe Indesign CS5: How can I access an image's name, file-type, and other properties?

Tags: image, adobe, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I am intermediate with Javascript, but am not so familiar with Adobe's "Extendscript". For practice and a better understanding of InDesign's code structure, I am trying to access properties of an image via `rectangles.images`.

Is this possible to access say, the file name of an image, through `rectangles.images`? Also I am interested if it's possible to access the image's color attributes this way, say to convert it to greyscale?

Here is my approach so far:

```
for(var i = 0; i < app.activeDocument.rectangles.length; i++)
{
    var imageType = app.activeDocument.rectangles[i].images.constructor.name;

    switch(imageType)
    {
        case "Images":
            alert(app.activeDocument.rectangles[i].images.name); // "name" is not a valid property here!
            break;

        default:
            alert("There are no images in this file.");
    }
}
```

Also, is it possible to determine the file-type of the image with `.rectangles.images.constructor.name`? I would like to add an extra case for say, PDF's or jpegs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldnt use the constructor unless you want to try and determine what type of JS Object it is which you dont need to do in this case because the `images` collection is only going to contain images. The file property will actually be on an image's related [`Link`](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs5/pc_Link.html) object.

Note none of this is tested i jsut took my knowledge of JS and the [API documentation](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs5/index_Layout%20Suite.html) and reworked your code...

```
var rect = app.activeDocument.rectangles,
    imgs,
    filePath,
    hasImages = false;

for(var i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) {
    imgs = rect[i].images;
    if( imgs.length > 0) {

      hasImages = true;
      for (var j = 0; j < imgs.length; j++) {
         filePath = imgs[j].itemLink ? imgs[j].itemLink.filePath : null; 
         switch (imgs[j].imageTypeName) {
             case 'jpeg':
                alert('This is a JPEG:' + filePath);
                break;
             case 'pdf':
                alert('This is a PDF: '+filePath);
                break;
             default:
               alert('Default case - '+imgs[j].imageTypeName+': '+filePath);
         }
      }
   }
} 

if(!hasImages) {
   alert('No images in document');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @prodigitalson! I was not aware of the `itemLink` and `filePath` properties until you had answered this question.

Comment: I got the file from another source , and its give me file path of that system, but when I export it into html , it gives me the image in separate folder, mean image are also encoded /attached into file